# Possible to setup Expresso Store default price modifiers and/or options?

Tags: expresso-store, javascript, fieldtype, modifiers

We have a store we're setting and we would like to be able to setup default price modifiers and/or options per channel since there are several modifiers per product and a large number of products need to be added. Is this possible in any way?

Anticipating a 'no', is there a JS API/Event model that I can tap into? If there is a JS event for the field initialisation and a JS API to add modifiers, I could implement this myself as an extension.

Comment: It's not really possible to set up default modifiers. Out of interest though, if you could do this, would you be happy just setting all modifiers up globally, or do you need to customize them per-product?

Comment: I'd need to be able to set them up per channel (ie: product line)

Comment: I'm in need of something like this–more for standardizing data entry on a per channel basis.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built into Store currently that would allow you to create modifiers on a per channel basis if you want the modifiers to adjust price or stock levels. There is currently a feature request for [Global Product Variations](https://exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests) that you can vote for.

If you do not not need to adjust the price, quantity or have a unique SKU for your variations you can use `input:custom_modifer_name="Custom Modifier Display Name"` of the `{exp:store:product}` tag ([docs here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#inputcustom_modifier_name)) to create the options at the template level. For something like size you can use the following"

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" input:size="Size"}

<select name="size">
  <option value="Small">Small</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="Large">Large</option>
</select>

{/exp:store:product}
```